# Select element by content

Tags: javascript, css

Within javascript, are you able to target elements on a page via psuedo classes? For example:

```
<table id="loginInnerTable">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">
    <span class="required">*</span><span> = required</span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>User ID <span class="required">*</span></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

How would I target the 'User ID' text to change it with .innerHTML? This is an example of a form that I don't have access to the code itself, except via JS.

Otherwise, what is the best method?

Comment: Do you have access to jQuery?

Comment: You can use JavaScript to delete the second row and then re-create it with the text label of you choice.  It looks like this table is not going to change much so you can rely on the table's DOM nodes remaining the same.

Comment: the <td> field holding the text doesn't have an idea nor a class. All you can do is loop over tds dom nodes until you find the one you want, but to it seems not very reliable...

Comment: Which pseudo class are you thinking about? AFAIK `:contains` doesn't exist anymore in the W3 spec (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#content-selectors )

Comment: Thanks for all the responses and different (yet similar) methods everyone. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always make use of DOM traversal and HTML DOM extensions. This depends on your actual markup though. In this specific case you can do the following:

Get a reference to the table:

```
var table = document.getElementById('loginInnerTable');
```

Get a reference to the second row:

```
var row = table.rows[1];
```

Get a reference to the first cell:

```
var cell = row.cells[0];
```

Change the value of the first child node (works because it is a text node):

```
cell.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Some new text';
```

Or iterate over all text nodes to find the right one (if you have mixed element and text nodes or the node you want to change is not the first child):

```
var node = cell.firstChild;
do {
    if (node.nodeType === 3 && node.nodeValue.indexOf('User ID') > -1) {
        node.nodeValue = 'Some new text';
        break;
    }
} while(node = node.nextSibling);
```

---

If you don't want to restrict your solution too much to the current structure (it might change from time to time), then iterating over all rows/cells and find the desired cell would be a more flexible approach. [Karl-André Gagnon showed this in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16300847/218196).

Comment: I would go for the direct non-loop approach.

Comment: [`node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType) ?

Comment: @deathApril: I *think* those constants are not available in all browsers. Or maybe it's only a problem in older IE versions where the DOM node constructor functions were not exposed.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this to select the element, then just use it as a reference to update using `innerHTML`

```
var userTD = document.getElementById('loginInnerTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].getElementsByTagName('td');
```

I'm not sure how efficient it is, but it should do the trick.

As others have mentioned it's not massively reliable - as if the table structure changes (which you say is out of your control) you'll have to change your code to work again.

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple code that will change the text :

```
var tdEl = document.getElementsByTagName('td')

for(var cpt = 0; cpt < tdEl.length; cpt++){
    if(tdEl[cpt].innerHTML.indexOf('User ID') != -1){
        tdEl[cpt].innerHTML = 'some text <span class="required">*</span>';
    }
}
```

If you want to make it a function (to reuse the code) :

```
changeNode('td', 'User ID', 'some text <span class="required">*</span>')

function changeNode(node, text, replace){
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName(node)
    for(var cpt = 0; cpt < el.length; cpt++){
        if(el[cpt].innerHTML.indexOf(text) != -1){
            el[cpt].innerHTML = replace;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother matching the string? I would just use the index for the second `<td>`, in fact, no need for the loop... if the table changes, the loop will probably fail anyway and the OP will need to adjust the JavaScript accordingly.

Comment: If he have more td to modify, he can make a function and passing the string to search. Or if he decide to add a row, he will not have to go in the JS files again. The loop wil not fail except if he change de td containing User Id

Answer (score 0):

> How would I target the 'User ID' text to change it with .innerHTML?

You won't. Of course you could do something like

```
var tab = document.getElementById('loginInnerTable');
tab.innerHTML = tab.innerHTML.replace("User ID", "something else");
```

but that would replace the whole table, crushing and re-parsing its DOM (and it won't work in IE, of course).

Instead, you will use DOM manipulation to get and change that text node:

```
var tab = document.getElementById('loginInnerTable'),
    td = tab.rows[1].cells[0],
    text = td.firstChild;
text.nodeValue = "something else";
```